# Saving an image in an Informix database using C# code?

Tags: c#, database, informix

How do I save an image in an Informix database using C# code?

At the moment, I'm unable to save an image in an Informix database using C# code.

All the steps work, only when the query is about to get executed it throws error "E42000: (-201) A syntax error has occurred."

Below is the code.

```
mycon.Open();
int len = Upload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
byte[] pic = new byte[len];
HttpPostedFile img = Upload.PostedFile;
Response.Write("Size of file = " + pic);
img.InputStream.Read(pic, 0, len);
//Upload.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(pic,0,len);
string str = "insert into imageinfo (name,address,photo) values('" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtaddress.Text + "'," + pic + ")";//,photo,@photo
mycmd = new OleDbCommand(str, mycon);
//mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(txtid.Text));
mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtaddress.Text);
mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", pic);
mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
mycon.Close();
lblMessage.Text = "Image details inserted successfully";
Response.Redirect("~/RetriveImage.aspx");
mycon.Close();
```

Comment: Did you tried anything? I guess no. Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Tried a lot but it is throwing some error "E42000: (-201) A syntax error has occurred."

Comment: Write your code, error message and more information on your spesific problem.

Comment: Well, fix the syntax error. Starts with the documentation - you use OleDb, OleDb does not use named parameters. Your insert has values, but you define parameters. This smells like "clueless, just mindlessly copied/pasted code together and now whining, never learned programming". Sorry if that sounds harsh, but this code SMELLS like it comes from two sources.

Comment: What is the type of the ImageInfo.Photo column in the Informix database?  The chances are all too good that you can't convert a string representation of the picture into that type.  Alternatively, it could be that your statement ends up being too long (that will depend on the version of Informix — the client code — that you are using, in part).  What to do depends on the type information.  If you're using a BLOB type (as opposed to CLOB, BYTE or TEXT), then you might use the `FILETOBLOB('client-file', 'client')` function in place of the string version of `pic`. ... or ...

Answer (score 1):

It starts with your code being a copy/paste mess from at least 2 sources because it makes no sense.

Your insert has the values directly - and you can not put pic in like that, sorry - but you define parameters that are not used. 2 sources code.

Then the code was mindlessly copy/pasted. You define named paraameters, but OleDb does not support named parameters (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/637db5d4-e205-489c-b127-7ca14abc48e3/) only parameter by position, which tells me you enver ever used parameters with Informix via OleDb and just copied/pasted the code together.

- Remove the direct data in the INSERT statement, put in parameter markers.
- Then use the parameters, as per the MS link I sent you (positional, marker is a ?).

Then it will work.

Occasionally it may require you to actually read the documentation instead of just stitching together code from different sources and asking for help.

Comment: Yeah, and now I get my crystal ball and make a magic ceremony to see your nice cleaned up code, with the full error reported like from a professional i an update on top? Or do you expect me to come over to your place for free and make your work?